# XQuery syntax to account for schema definition

Tags: sql, xml, xquery-sql

Environment: SQL Server 2012.

Say I have a table Message with xml column WordIndex. I also have a table Word which has WordId and WordText. Xml for Message.WordIndex has the following schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.com">
    <xs:element name="wi">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="w">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="p" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="wid" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and some data to go with it:

```
<wi xmlns="http://www.example.com">
  <w wid="1">
    <p>28</p>
    <p>72</p>
    <p>125</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="4">
    <p>89</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="5">
    <p>11</p>
  </w>
</wi>
```

I also have SQL queries with XQuery code like this:

```
with WordIds as
(
    select distinct
        t.c.value('@wid', 'int') as XmlWordId
    from
        Message as m
        cross apply
            m.WordIndex.nodes('/wi/w') as t(c)
    inner join Word as w
        on w.WordId = t.c.value('@wid', 'int')

-- some more joins go here ...
)
select
    count(*)
from
    WordIds
```

and this (this one doesn't work, since I started to introduce schema into it):

```
with xmlnamespaces('http://www.example.com' as ns)
select
    wi.Position,
    w.WordId,
    w.WordText
from
(
    select
        t.c.value('.', 'int') as Position,
        t.c.value('../@wid', 'int') as WordId
    from
        Message as m
        cross apply m.WordIndex.nodes('//p') as t(c)
    where
        m.MessageId = @MessageId
) as wi
inner join Word as w
    on w.WordId = wi.WordId
order by
    wi.Position
```

**Question:**

What is the proper syntax to qualify arguments to calls to .value() and .nodes()?
I get errors that I don't fully understand:

```
XQuery [Message.WordIndex.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:anyAtomicType *'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these queries:

```
;with xmlnamespaces( default 'http://www.example.com'), WordIds as 
( 
    select distinct 
        t.c.value('@wid', 'int') as XmlWordId 
    from 
        Message as m 
        cross apply 
            m.WordIndex.nodes('/wi/w') as t(c) 
    inner join Word as w 
        on w.WordId = t.c.value('@wid', 'int') 

-- some more joins go here ... 
) 
select 
    count(*) 
from 
    WordIds 


;with xmlnamespaces( default 'http://www.example.com')
select 
    w.c.value('@wid', 'INT') wid,
    p.c.value('.', 'INT') p
from message m
    cross apply m.wordIndex.nodes('wi/w') w(c)
        cross apply w.c.nodes('p') p(c)
```

Generally, try and avoid the parent axis(..) as it has performance issues.  Instead use multiple CROSS APPLY to drill down into the xml left to right.

Have a look through this article for more info on namespaces:

Adding Namespaces Using WITH XMLNAMESPACES

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why is there a semicolon before "with"

Comment: It's just one of the rules when using WITH, either with namespaces or common table expressions (CTEs).

Comment: What significance does it have, besides ability to append the query to another one? It works fine without ";"

Comment: Followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342767/search-for-multiple-values-in-anxml-column

Answer (score 1):

It's just one of the syntactic rules, quote from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

"When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon."